# Is it possible to put a 'new folder' in with the standard toolbar buttons?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, toolbar

I suspect the short answer is 'no', but here goes anyway..

For context - under Windows XP, when looking at a folder window, choosing view;toolbars;customize, brings up the 'customize toolbar' dialog.  This has 'available toolbar buttons' on the left, and 'current toolbar buttons' on the right.

Now there's a lot of nifty stuff you can select, but the one thing that never seems to be available is the 'new folder' option.  This can't be an alien concept, as a look at the standard save-as dialog will usually reveal a short row of toolbar-like buttons, one of which has the tool tip "create new folder".

Is there some way to get that functionality onto the regular folder window toolbar?  This would be handy because mousing into the File menu, the 'new folder' option isn't always in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with:

- Create a new text file. Name it `New Folder.vbs`
- Copy-paste the following script into
  it:

```
dim myShell
set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
myShell.sendkeys("%(f)")
WScript.Sleep 200
myShell.sendkeys("w{ENTER}")
```

- Move the vbs file somewhere and create a shortcut to it under to `C:\Documents and Settings\<your_user>\Favorites\Favorites Bar`
- Change the shortcut name to "New Folder" and set the icon accordingly.
- Open Windows Explorer and check View Menu -> Toolbars -> Links

Your New Folder item will now be visible.

[image]

Of course, if you use Internet Explorer, you will have to put up with this new item on its favorites bar!

Comment: I chose this one b/c it's a relatively painless DIY.

Answer (score 4):

With the standard buttons? I don't think so. If you don't mind extensions, check out [**StExBar**](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar):

[image]

StExBar is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has this built in, but you probably aren't looking to upgrade.

Comment: well, actually, i am looking forward to getting 7 where possible; i'm just trying to make life easier on the XP machines i can't do anything about upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Or just go to view > toolbars > links

The link bar will appear. Unlock the "link" toolbar and move it around until you like its position (NOTE: I moved mine in the same horizontal row with my standard buttons. Then delete the default favorites in that bar. Then create any shortcut you want using right click > new > shortcut, and enter the folder location or the URL of the page, and then name the shortcut as you wish. When done the shortcut icon can be changes to any .ico file you want. I store my .ico files in c > Windows . System32 > Resources, and create a folder called "Shortcut Icons". Then simply click and drag the shortcuts onto the link bar (still unlocked) and then delete the original shortcuts wherever you created them from. You now have a nice toolbar on your file explorer header with nice icons that will open any folder on your hard drive, over the LAN, or engage any .exe file, or will engage your default browser and take you to any website URL inserted into that shortcut. Then lock the toolbar down and move on.